# How to store pdf and png to postgres DB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql

I have tried to save pdf and png to postgres DB but not able to store the file in the db for future use.

i have created an api for storing the user info in those info i also wanted to store the pdf(resume) and png(profile pic) file of a user.

Below you can find my api
using **bytea d-type** for pdf and png

```
const pool = require("../../DBConnection/DBConnection");

exports.uploadResume = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { firstName, lastName, email, profilePic } = req.body;
    console.log(firstName);
    const newUser = await pool.query(
      `INSERT INTO au_resume_uploader (first_name, last_name, email, resume, profilePic ) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *`,
      [firstName, lastName, email, resume, profilePic ]
    );
    res.json(newUser);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
};
```

Looking for solution how to store the
**Any other alternative approach also be help full**,
tried using multer but not got any thing

Answer (score 1):

You should upload your media files(images and pdfs) to a cloud service like AWS, google cloud etc. Or if you are working locally then to a media folder.

You can then store its path in your db.

Since You are using DB I am assuming you are using some sort of backend system So you may refer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-uploading-in-react-js/

Comment: You can also upload to a media folder when you're not working locally

Comment: actually i am pretty new to all this related to image storing,  can you suggest any repo or some blogs.

Comment: Since You are using DB I am assuming you are using some sort of backend system 
So you may refer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-uploading-in-react-js/ @RockHavmor

Answer (score 1):

Typically we save path or file names to the database. And store the actual files in any file management system like one drive, google cloud...

Comment: actually i am pretty new to all this related to image storing, can you suggest any repo or some blogs.

Comment: Check this [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) package.
[Random blog](https://www.bacancytechnology.com/blog/file-upload-using-multer-with-nodejs-and-express)